# How to create a SQL table using php IF date is equal to X

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a MySQL table using a PHP IF statement. I am able to create the table using an IF statement; although the problem I am running into is that the table only gets created when the date is >= to X, as opposed to how I would like to specify the statement; IF the date is == X.

How can I automatically create this SQL table IF the date is == X,
and, is there a way to create this table without having to go to the page where the table data will be displayed and refresh the page?

Here is my code:

```
$timezone       = date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
$TheDate        = time("F j, g:i a");

$servername = "server";
$username = "user";
$password = "pass";
$dbname = "db";
$conn = mysqli_connect('server', 'user', 'pass');
(!$conn->set_charset("utf-8"));

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_error());
}
mysqli_select_db($conn, $dbname);

if ($TheDate == strtotime("April 24, 9:53 pm")) {

$CreateTable = "CREATE TABLE issue11 (
ID INT(5) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
First VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
Last VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
Title VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
StoryLink VARCHAR(140) NOT NULL,
Genre VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
About VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL,
Link VARCHAR(125) NOT NULL,
Picture VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
ALT VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)";


mysqli_query($conn, $CreateTable);
mysqli_close($conn);
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a very contrived case. Why would you want to allow the creation of a table only once each year on April 24 at exactly 9:53 p.m. (not a second earlier or later!)? It is more customary to create a table *once* and then add, change or delete appropriate values later on ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is no problem with the above code ,

The main problem is

> The code in the if condition will only work if you run this page at
>   "April 24, 9:53 pm" (the date you specified for equality).How can you do that , I mean the time is constantly changing and you can't do this checking each time when time changes using php alone.

Idea is by using **ajax call** 

Using ajax 
one way is to make an ajax request to run the above code each second , and its not an effective and efficient way to do.

Another way would be to do the checking at the client side and do the operation (create table) only when the if returns `true` using an ajax call to the page where you wrote the above code.

Comment: So, this code will only create the table at exactly April 24, 9:53 pm? Not a second later? I didn't specify seconds within the IF statement in my code. I thought I could refresh during that whole minute and have the table created.

Comment: for the seconds part , it will be `00` by default ,no need to specify.

Comment: maybe you can do `if ($TheDate >= strtotime("April 24, 9:53 pm") && ($TheDate <= strtotime("April 24, 9:54 pm")) )`  to achieve what you want.